# Node server runs perfectly on localhost but not at all on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've got a server which I've developed on localhost, and I thought that Heroku would be a good stepping stone to going live. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work.

More specifically, I can get Heroku to build well enough, but it crashes as soon as I try to access my website.

Heroku logs are as follows:

```
2019-06-30T18:34:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user tomdothosker@gmail.com
2019-06-30T18:34:24.381150+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7f8cce5d by user tomdothosker@gmail.com
2019-06-30T18:34:24.381150+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user tomdothosker@gmail.com
2019-06-30T18:34:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-06-30T18:34:25.695607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2019-06-30T18:34:26.034203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-06-30T18:34:26.966179+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-06-30T18:34:27.034914+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-06-30T18:34:29.568812+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-06-30T18:34:32.418305+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-06-30T18:34:32.418320+00:00 app[web.1]: > cyprus@1.0.0 start /app
2019-06-30T18:34:32.418324+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-06-30T18:34:32.418325+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-06-30T18:34:33.279874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-06-30T18:34:32.889328+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running at https://localhost:59348/
2019-06-30T18:34:34.982611+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=kingdom-of-cyprus.herokuapp.com request_id=5f8137a5-c584-4b40-8089-58ba67f88de3 fwd="165.120.137.21" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-06-30T18:34:35.256350+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kingdom-of-cyprus.herokuapp.com request_id=6223ae91-d44d-4762-a9d9-971f923a5cc8 fwd="165.120.137.21" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

From what I can tell from the logs, the site starts as it's supposed to, then crashes immediately. Which I know makes no sense. Any ideas what's going on here?

---

If it helps, `server.js` can be found [here](https://github.com/tomhosker/kingdom-of-cyprus/blob/master/server.js). The interesting stuff starts at around line 266.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run on `https://localhost:59348/`, are you hardcoding that somewhere?

Comment: @ColinRicardo, with a port number like that it's likely that OP is correctly using the `PORT` environment variable that Heroku provides.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your `server.js` to us.

Comment: As requested, I've edited the question to include my `server.js`. It's 400 lines, so I've included it as a link - although (I think) the stuff you'll be interested in can be found around line 266. Apologies for the delay.